# gnu screen: automatic session on split

Tags: gnu-screen, session, command, split

Inactive region appears after 'split' command in gnu screen now. You must go to the new region and type :screen. Only after that shell session appears in this region.

Is it possible to make new region with shell session or other program? Not from config file, but from running screen.

Comment: I suggest you to read this answer :

http://superuser.com/questions/94612/macros-in-gnu-screen

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688630/9689