# Why doesn't GNU Screen split show up for remote user?

Tags: gnu-screen, remote, split

I have a screen session running on my local machine:

```
~/test@example.com$screen -S pair
```

Then, turn on multiuser:

```
ctrl-a:multiuser on
```

Finally, allow the user `pair` to connect to the session:

```
ctrl-a:acladd pair
```

So far so good. A remote user can log into the machine as pair and connect to the session:

```
~/$ssh pair@example.io
pair@example~/$screen -x test/pair
```

But, if I open a split:

```
ctrl-a:|
```

The user `pair` cannot see the split.

Is it possible to have multiple splits open in a shared session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out screen now has a `layout` facility that will keep track of splits. In order for the pair to see the current `layout` just save it as the default:

```
ctrl-a:layout save default
```

Answer (score 1):

The split is done in the `screen` client, not in the screen session itself. `pair` may split his screen any way he wants, independent of your split.

Comment: Is it possible to create a split that anyone in the session can see?

Comment: You might find this answer to a related question useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1985/119010

Comment: I believe `tmux` can do that, as it separates the notions of sessions, windows and panes.

Comment: Thanks @katti! I actually use `tmux` all the time (though iterm2) but I didn't think it supported multiuser as well as `screen`. Do you know if it's possible to have 2 users on the same system share a session with `tmux`?